# RxJava2 get latest value if it fresh enought or request new one

Tags: rx-java2

I need observable which will be able to return latest emitted data or request new one if it is expired while at the same time allowing force updates.

Comment: Use `defer` operator http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html

Comment: There is a lot of ways how to achieve that. Describe what do you got so far and then we can help you to tie all necessary parts together.